# How to use a slash in Spirit Lex patterns?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-lex

Code below compiles fine with

> clang++ -std=c++11 test.cpp -o test

But when running an exception is thrown

> terminate called after throwing an instance of
>   'boost::lexer::runtime_error'
>       what():  Lookahead ('/') is not supported yet.

The problem is the the slash (/) in input and/or regex (line 12 and 39) but I can't find a solution how to escape it right. Any hints?

```
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <boost/spirit/include/lex.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/lex_lexertl.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>

namespace lex        = boost::spirit::lex;
namespace qi         = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace phoenix    = boost::phoenix;

std::string regex("FOO/BAR");

template <typename Type>
struct Lexer : boost::spirit::lex::lexer<Type> {
    Lexer() : foobar_(regex) {
        this->self.add(foobar_);
    }
    boost::spirit::lex::token_def<std::string> foobar_;
};

template <typename Iterator, typename Def>
struct Grammar
  : qi::grammar <Iterator, qi::in_state_skipper<Def> > {
    template <typename Lexer> Grammar(const Lexer & _lexer);
    typedef qi::in_state_skipper<Def> Skipper;
    qi::rule<Iterator, Skipper> rule_;
};
template <typename Iterator, typename Def>
template <typename Lexer>
Grammar<Iterator, Def>::Grammar(const Lexer & _lexer)
  : Grammar::base_type(rule_) {
    rule_ = _lexer.foobar_;
}

int main() {
    // INPUT
    char const * first("FOO/BAR");
    char const * last(first + strlen(first));

    // LEXER
    typedef lex::lexertl::token<const char *> Token;
    typedef lex::lexertl::lexer<Token> Type;
    Lexer<Type> l;

    // GRAMMAR
    typedef Lexer<Type>::iterator_type Iterator;
    typedef Lexer<Type>::lexer_def Def;
    Grammar<Iterator, Def> g(l);

    // PARSE
    bool ok = lex::tokenize_and_phrase_parse (
        first
      , last
      , l
      , g
      , qi::in_state("WS")[l.self]
    );

    // CHECK
    if (!ok || first != last) {
        std::cout << "Failed parsing input file" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'd say simplify this so it works without the `/` (i.e. make it just read and parse `FOOBAR`). Then, once you get that working, try adding the `/` back in.

Answer (score 1):

As [sehe points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31408531/how-to-use-a-slash-in-spirit-lex-patterns/31408891?noredirect=1#comment50793571_31408891), `/` is likely intended to be used as a lookahead operator, likely taking after [the syntax of flex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946070/bison-flex-peek-at-the-next-letter-or-token/4982579#4982579). It's unfortunate that Spirit wouldn't use more [normal lookahead syntax](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) (not that I think that other syntax is more elegant; it just gets confusing with all the subtle variations in regex syntax).

If you look at `re_tokeniser.hpp`:

```
// Not an escape sequence and not inside a string, so
// check for meta characters.
switch (ch_)
{
    ...
    case '/':
        throw runtime_error("Lookahead ('/') is not supported yet.");
        break;
    ...
}
```

It thinks you're not in an escape sequence nor are you inside a string, so it's checking for meta characters. `/` is considered a meta character for lookahead (even though the feature isn't implemented), and must be escaped, [despite the Boost docs not mentioning that at all](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/lex/quick_reference/lexer.html).

Try escaping the `/` (not in the input) with a backslash (i.e. `"\\/"`, or `"\/"` if using a raw string). Alternatively, [others have suggested using `[/]`](https://botbot.me/freenode/openscad/2015-06-13/?msg=41767337&page=1).

I'd consider this a bug in the Spirit Lex documentation for it lacking to point out that `/` must be escaped.

---

**Edit:** kudos to [sehe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31408531/how-to-use-a-slash-in-spirit-lex-patterns/31408891?noredirect=1#comment50793571_31408891) and [cv_and_he](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31408531/how-to-use-a-slash-in-spirit-lex-patterns/31408891?noredirect=1#comment50794942_31408891), who helped correct some of my earlier thinking. If they post an answer here, be sure to give them a +1.

Comment: I've tried to escape the slash with "\\/", "\/" and "[\]". No solution worked out.

Comment: It fails with a different error, though. (Specifically: `Assertion failed: (std::size_t(~0) != state), function set_lexer_state, file /usr/local/include/boost/spirit/home/lex/qi/state_switcher.hpp, line 87.`). I don't know Spirit very well, but it sounds like you have another issue in your lexer/parser. This answer should be correct for solving the slash issue. For the other issue... I'm not sure what to say.

Comment: It's not the ordered choice. Also referring to PEG specification notation is a red herring because we're not specifying a grammar here. We're specifying token patterns. They use a subset of regular expressions: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/lex/quick_reference/lexer.html (and incidentally, this is what the error message suggested)

Comment: @Cornstalks The new error is due to the fact that the "WS" state does not exist and the skipper tries to use it. [This example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2f06aed772d95b9f) tries to add said state and seems to work.

Comment: @sehe: If it's not ordered choice, then what is it? From your link, `/` isn't a special character, and so should be recognized by itself. Yet it's not, and causes an error unless it is escaped.

Comment: @cv_and_he: Nice! Good observation.

Comment: @Cornstalks I don't know. I didn't write an answer for a reaon :) The error message seems to hold a  pretty solid clue though. Simply because you cannot think of something else, doesn't make it an ordered choice, nor related to PEG.

Comment: @sehe I also don't know but a little googling makes me think that the error is refering to Spirit.Lex not supporting [this feature](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4982579/2417774) of flex.

Comment: @sehe: Well, I think you've got a decent point, and have included your thoughts in my answer.